# Boot-sector size is constant?

Tags: boot, bootloader, partitioning

I read that first sector on any partition needs to be reserved for bootloader, regardless of weather it is used or not. But sector sizes changed from 512 to 4096 bytes. So how much space must really be reserved?

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need to worry about such details unless you're designing filesystems, filesystem utilities, etc.; system tools like `mkfs` create the filesystems you ask in the appropriate way, no matter what the filesystem type. (If they don't, then that constitutes a bug.)

If you're asking about this out of curiosity, then you've pretty much answered your own question: If the first sector must be reserved, then the number of bytes reserved depends on the sector size of the device under discussion. If the data structure, such as a filesystem, uses bytes rather than sectors as its primary unit of measure, then it will either reserve enough bytes to cover all likely sector sizes or risk damage should some tool overwrite its entire first sector on a disk with over-512-byte sectors.

One more point: Although reserving the first sector (or sometimes several sectors) for boot loader code is common, I don't believe it's universal -- certainly not when you count non-filesystem partitions. An extended partition, for instance, stores partition data in its first sector. Although there's room there that's unused, a partition boot loader that used the whole of the first sector would trash an extended partition. I've heard that putting a boot loader in a Linux swap partition will cause problems, but I've never investigated this in any depth.

Comment: I am designing a filesystem.

Comment: In that case, I recommend you dig through the source code to the Linux kernel's filesystems and the related utilities (mkfs, etc.).